# When does fabric create app

Tags: ios, google-fabric

Especially I'm interested when a new app will be created in the Fabric dashboard. Will it be created after xcodebuild command or after some application has been launched. In my case I have to skip building archive which calls Fabric/run in build phases. Any way to avoid build phase to create an app on Fabric?

Answer (score 1):

Mike from Fabric here.

For an app to activate on Fabric, we need both a build and run of the app with Fabric active and configured. There is no way to skip both the build and run at this point in time.